# How often does $\pi$ contain a sequence of digits $x$ at decimal place $x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pi

Today, I came across an interesting bit of trivia. The decimal expansion of $\pi$ contains the sequence of digits $79873884$ starting at decimal place $79873884$.

This is not unique, since another (perhaps trivial) example would be $1$ at decimal place $1$. But I wonder if there are more of these occurences.

Can anything be said about the frequency of these sequences? Are there infinitely many?

Comment: @fleablood by regular you mean [GK-Regular](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GK-Regular.html)?

Comment: Actually I meant "normal".  I don't know what Gauss-Korman distribution is, but I probably mean it as well.

Answer (score 6):

If we assume the digits of $\pi$ are a random sequence, the probability of the digits $d_1d_2...d_k$ (with $d_1\neq 0$) occurring at a particular place is $10^{-k}$. Since there are $9\cdot 10^{k-1}$ such sequences, the expected number of such occurrences in the range of $[10^{k-1},10^k)$-th digits of $\pi$ is $0.9$.

Thus we would expect $0.9\log_{10} n$ occurrences in the first $n$ digits of $\pi$, or infinitely many in all digits of $\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

[This sequence](https://oeis.org/A057680) shows the first few (you missed 16470 and 44899). According to the discussion on that page, it should be expected there are infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect they are very rare, since at place $x$ about $\log_{10}x$ digits would have to match, each with probability $1/10$, so probability about
$$
\left( \frac{1}{10} \right)^{\log x} = \frac{1}{x}.
$$

**Edit:** Other answers contradict my intuition. I'll leave this up anyway, but no longer believe it.